# How do I implement this kind of event listener design?

Tags: c#, .net, events

I am new to C# so this is probably me just not understanding something fundamental or missing out on some feature of the language. I've searched online but all the examples I seem to find have everything all in one class (in other words, they define the event as well as the method that executes when the event is triggered), which is not what I want.

For my scenario I'd like to define an interface of listener methods that can accept some custom parameters (this would be my own EventArgs right?) that provide instructions. Lets pretend its for a car, so I have methods named:

- Start(MyCustomParameters par)
- Accelerate(MyCustomParameters par)
- Decelerate(MyCustomParameters par)

and then I want to be able to create classes that provide the actual implementation of these methods.

completely separate from all this, I have a single class that executes periodically based on an external process and I want it to be responsible for triggering these events (when the car starts and accelerates etc).

That's the basics of what I'm trying to get working but no luck so far. Also, one follow-up question. If my listener-implementation class needs to maintain any kind of state from a given call, how best to do that (e.g. say that when Accelerate is called it wants to be able to return the speed that it accelearted to back to the invoker of the event - e.g. 80 kph)

hope you can help SO, thank you very much

Comment: I think you are looking for Dependency Injection.  You will need the implementation classes, a class to manage the instantiation of the implementations and then a listener class that handles the business logic of the implementations.  You need to determine the return types of the interface methods so your handler/listener can perform the necessary actions when triggered.

Comment: @Evan L I actually did some reading on DI just the other day and while it seems cool, it seems way overkill for something simple like this where I just want one class to trigger events and another to handle them? What makes you say DI is necessary here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a simple example of event/listener in c# :

```
 //your custom parameters class
    public class MyCustomParameters
    {
        //whatever you want here...
    }

    //the event trigger
    public class EventTrigger
    {
        //declaration of the delegate type
        public delegate void AccelerationDelegate(MyCustomParameters parameters);

        //declaration of the event
        public event AccelerationDelegate Accelerate;

        //the method you call to trigger the event
        private void OnAccelerate(MyCustomParameters parameters)
        {
            //actual triggering of the events
            if (Accelerate != null)
                Accelerate(parameters);
        }
    }

    //the listener
    public class Listener
    {
        public Listener(EventTrigger trigger)
        {
            //the long way to subscribe to the event (to understand you create a delegate)
            trigger.Accelerate += new EventTrigger.AccelerationDelegate(trigger_Accelerate);

            //a shorter way to subscribe to the event which is equivalent to the statement above
            trigger.Accelerate += trigger_Accelerate;
        }

        void trigger_Accelerate(MyCustomParameters parameters)
        {
            //implement event handling here
        }
    }
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your example highlights my confusion but also is helping me understand I think. That OnAccelerate method is not the implementation of the listener, it is just the code that triggers the event right? I think I was confusing the two previously. Do you have to pass in a reference to the EventTrigger to the listener? That seems like an odd coupling...is that just how it works in C#?

Comment: Yes, a call to the OnAccelerate method triggers the event. And yes, you have to pass a reference to the eventTrigger to the listener(s). But if you don't want to deal with an EventTrigger's instance, you can also declare the event Accelerate as **static** and subscribe to the event directly on the class : **EventTrigger.Accelerate += trigger_Accelerate;**